# primality test function is_prime (n, k) based on Fermat Little Theorem,

Tags: python, primes, primality-test

I solved this question: Implement a primality test function is_prime (n, k) based on Fermat Little Theorem, where n is the number to be tested, and k is the number of bases to be used. The function should return False if n is not prime, and True if n is pseudoprime to these k bases. Notice that k is a small constant, and therefore, some composites will be counted as primes.

```
def is_prime (n, k) :
    bases = []
    for i in range(2,k+1):
        bases.append(i)
    for base in bases:
       a =  math.pow(base,n-1) % n
       if (a==1):
           return True
           
       else:
           False
```

## testing for primes under 20000, for k = 10

```
bases = int(input("Enter the number of bases: "))

for m in range(1,2000):

    print(is_prime(m,bases))
    print(m)
```

this the error:

```
 File "/Users/IA/Desktop/ICS254_Project/project.py", line 48, in <module>
    print(is_prime(m,bases))
  File "/Users/IA/Desktop/ICS254_Project/project.py", line 30, in is_prime
    a =  math.pow(base,n-1) % n
OverflowError: math range error
```

What is wrong and how can I correct it?

Comment: 1. Don't use `math.pow`, use the builtin [`pow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow). 2. Use 3-argument form of pow: pow(base, exponent, modulus).

Comment: why should use 3 args?   def is_prime (n, k) :
    bases = []
    for i in range(2,k+1):
        bases.append(i)
    for base in bases:
       a =  pow(base,n-1,n) % n
       if (a==1):
           return True
           
       else:
           False

      
      
#print(is_prime(5,3))

# testing for primes under 20000, for k = 10

bases = int(input("Enter the number of bases: "))

for m in range(1,2000):

    print(is_prime(m,bases))
    print(m)